# What's the best way to compare the equality of two DateTime's in C#... but only to a certain precision?

Tags: c#, datetime, date

I have two datetimes, one from a timestamp, and another I'm generating in code.  I need to test their equality, and would love to do it without too many expressions.  Here's an example of my two dates:

```
DateTime expireTimeStampUTC = 
    DateTime.Parse(UTCValueFromDatabase));
DateTime expectedExpireTime = 
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(NumberOfExpectedHoursInConfig);
```

This is too high precision of a test:

if (expireTimeStampUTC.Equals(expectedExpireTime)){}

I don't care if they're exact to the second, just the hour.

Could it possibly be the best solution to do something compound like this:

```
if (expireTimeStampUTC.Date.Equals(expectedExpireTime.Date))
{
    if (!expireTimeStampUTC.Hour.Equals(expectedExpireTime.Hour))
    {
        pass = false;
    }
}
```

I'm not the most experienced with C#... is there some elegent way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the problem you are having is because of them is a database type, you could convert to that type and compare there, we lose/gain about a millisecond converting to SQLDateTimes on roughly 1/3 of DB saves.

If not, compare the unit you actually care about:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(59); // or 1 or 61 for test values;

// if the dates are in the same hour (12:10 == 12:50, 1:58 != 2:02)
if(dt1.Hour == dt2.Hour) // result
```

or if you care that they are within an hour time span

```
// if the dates are within one hour of each other (1:58 == 2:02, 3:30 != 4:45)
if((dt1 - dt2).Duration() < TimeSpan.FromHours(1)) // result
```

Here subtracting dates generates a time span, the duration is the 'absolute value' and then we create the limit explicitly from a unit we care about (FromHours) and compare.

The last line is as clean as I can think to do equality within a particular time span.

Comment: Actually I think this is actually better style.  I think it's clearer what's happening.  I've never changed the "right answer" token before, but I think in this case, this is the better solution.

Comment: Fair enough. I think it's six one/half a dozen the other. The "Duration()" syntax might be more readable, but it has the (admittedly negligible) overhead of newing up a TimeSpan on both sides of the comparison.

Answer (score 6):

How about finding the difference between the two hours, and seeing if it's below a certain threshold (say 3600 seconds for an hour)?

```
var diff = expireTimeStamp.Subtract(expectedExpireTime).TotalSeconds;
pass = Math.Abs(diff) < 3600;
```

Comment: Excellent... that was the answer so stupidly obvious I would kick myself for not thinking of it.  Thanks.  And with a code sample too.  Magical.

Comment: Maybe not in *your* C#! Time to upgrade to Visual Studio 2008, mate! :)

Comment: Wild.  I think my dev lead would shoot me if I started using that.

Comment: Nothing harmful about "var". In my code snippet above it's totally obvious what the "diff" variable means, and you don't care about its compile-time type. (Is it Double? Int? Long? Who cares?)

Answer (score 4):

Subtract them.  Check whether the resulting [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(VS.80).aspx) is within a certain maximum range.

Comment: DateTime values support the subtraction operation. you get a TimeSpan, you check if it is smaller than the specified interval.

Comment: That's pretty much what I just said.

Answer (score 1):

Construct new DateTime objects and compare them. In C#, there's very little penalty for constructing "throwaway" objects in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the problem when trying to write unit tests which committed then retrieved business objects. I was trying to use the "StartTime" property of my object to ensure the object could be retrieved and encountered this problem. The "StartTime" value committed in the database lost 6 digits of precision in the Ticks value!

Here's how I rewrote my test condition so my test would perform correctly and pass. Relevant line is second-to-last line of block.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
NewEventInfo testEvent1 = FakeEvent("test01action", start); //plus other params for testing
mServiceClient.AddEvent(testEvent1);

EventInfo[] eventInfos = null; //code to get back events within time window

Assert.IsNotEmpty(eventInfos);
Assert.GreaterOrEqual(eventInfos.Length, 1);

EventInfo resultEvent1 = eventInfos.FirstOrDefault(e => 
e.Action == "test01action" &&
Math.Abs(e.StartTime.Subtract(testEvent1.StartTime).TotalMilliseconds) < 1000); //checks dates are within 1 sec
Assert.IsNotNull(resultEvent1);
```

This way I could be sure the object was the one committed by the unit test, as the EventInfo.StartTime property only uses date times with precision of 1 second.

EDIT: Added Math.Abs(around DateTime diff) to ensure absolute value being compared to 1000.